# Young boy living on Mars discovers that his parents are robots

Tags: story-identification, movie

As a young boy in the 70's or early 80's, I watched a movie which took place on Mars. There was a family living and the boy discovered that his parents where robots.
That's all I can remember. Does anyone know such a movie?

Comment: http://www.nerdist.com/2013/06/weird-old-sci-fi-invaders-from-mars/?

Comment: How did he know that they were robots? Are you certain it was Mars?

Comment: what a nice site. I was searching the other questions and stumbled on the answer. The Martian Chronicles (1980)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWen9WZhztU

Comment: My memories tricked me. It was the boy who was not human. He was martian.

Comment: Tee-hee. Calvin and Hobbes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the TV mini-series [The Martian Chronicles](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080242/) (1980)

My memories tricked me. It was the boy who was not human. He was martian!